# Problemas com vetor e strcpy() em linguagem C

Tags: c, array, algoritmo

Estou tentando fazer um vetor com 23 nomes, que deve sortear 11 salgados, 6 doces e 6 bebidas sem repetição, o sorteio deve ser feito em números de 1 à 3 e quando é sorteado deve ser atribuído um valor em caracteres, e no final deve ser informado ao usuário os nomes e o item que foi sorteado.

A parte de informar os nomes está ok, porém ele finaliza sem informar os itens

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char nomes[23];
    char itens[23];
    int i,x,contador1,contador2,contador3;
    char item[10];
    int volta;

    for(i=0;i<=22;i++)
    {
        printf("Digite o nome: ");
        scanf("%s",&nomes[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<=22;i++)
    {
        volta = 1;
        while (volta)
        {
            x = rand() % 3;
            if((x==0) && (contador1<11))
            {
                strcpy(item,"salgado");
                contador1 = contador1 + 1;
                volta = 2;
            }
            else if((x==1) && (contador2<6))
            {
                strcpy(item,"doce");
                contador2 = contador2 + 1;
                volta = 2;
            }
            else if((x==2) && (contador3<6))
            {
                strcpy(item,"bebida");
                contador3 = contador3 + 1;
                volta = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                volta = 1;
            }
        }
        itens[i] = item;
    }
    for(i=0;i<=22;i++)
    {
        printf("Aluno: %s ficou com: %s ", nomes[i], itens[i]);
    }
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem diversos erros aí e este código nem compila, vamos lá:

- Faltou incluir o cabeçalho `string.h` para poder usar a função `strcpy()`.
- Está declarando uma *string* com 22 caracteres válidos e não 23 *strings*. Para fazer o que deseja tem que reservar espaço para cada item e para os caracteres, lembrando de reservar um byte para o terminador.
- Aí tem que mudar a forma como pega os dados com `scanf()`.
- Não está inicializando as variáveis contadoras, então pega lixo inicial e tudo pode acontecer

Não é erro, mas algumas coisas poderiam ser melhores:

- O laço de repetição está confuso e não precisa de tudo isto, pode ter menos variáveis
- Os nomes de variáveis podem ser melhores e não precisa declarar tudo antes
- Comparar se é menor que 23 é mais idiomático e intuitivo do que fazer se for menor ou igual a 22
- Idealmente seria melhor usar um [algoritmo Fisher-Yates](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136206/101), este código é bem ineficiente e tem potencial até de entrar em laço infinito, embora na prática não acontecerá
- O código pode ser um pouco mais organizado.

Assim funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char nomes[23][31];
    char itens[23][8];
    int contadorSalgado = 0, contadorDoce = 0, contadorBebida = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
        printf("Digite o nome: ");
        scanf("%s", nomes[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
        while (1) {
            int sorteado = rand() % 3;
            if (sorteado == 0 && contadorSalgado < 11) {
                strcpy(itens[i], "salgado");
                contadorSalgado++;
                break;
            }
            else if (sorteado == 1 && contadorDoce < 6) {
                strcpy(itens[i], "doce");
                contadorDoce++;
                break;
            }
            else if (sorteado == 2 && contadorBebida < 6) {
                strcpy(itens[i], "bebida");
                contadorBebida++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) printf("Aluno: %s ficou com: %s\n", nomes[i], itens[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/eBmORN). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/RandomMatch). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/RandomMatch.c).