# Programa de bingo não identifica quem venceu

Tags: c, matriz, random

Tentando fazer um bingo com matriz em C, porém a verificação dos valores sorteados não identifica corretamente com a matriz.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));

    int sorteio = 0;
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0; 
    int c1[4][4], c2[4][4],i, j;

    for(i = 0;i < 4; i++ ){
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            c1[i][j] = rand()%50;
            c2[i][j] = rand()%50;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0;i < 4; i++ ){
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            printf("%i ",c1[i][j]);
            }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0;i < 4; i++ ){
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            printf("%i ",c2[i][j]);
            }
        printf("\n");
    }

    sorteio = rand() %50;
    printf ("%i ", sorteio);    

    while (p1 <= 16 || p2 <= 16){

        for(i = 0;i < 4; i++ ){
            for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                if (c1[i][j] == sorteio){
                    p1++;}  
                if (c2[i][j] == sorteio){
                    p2++;}
                }
            }

    sorteio = rand() %50;
    printf ("%i ", sorteio);


    if (p1 == 16){
        printf("\nBingo! Jogador 1 ganhou\n");
        return 0;}
        else{   
            if (p2 == 16){
                printf("\nBingo! Jogador 2 ganhou\n");
                return 0;}
                else{
                    printf("empate");
                    return 0;}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem diversos erros aí, vou deixar pra lá os pequenos, vamos ao principal que ocorre mais de uma vez:

- Para sortear números sem repetição de forma correta e eficiente deve usar o [algoritmo Fisher-Yates](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136206/101)
- Pelo mesmo motivo o sorteio pode, potencialmente, pegar números eternamente e não sortear todos, além de sortear algo repetido
- Na verdade ainda tem um outro erro conceitual, porque as cartelas não são montadas de forma aleatória, há um critério, mas vou considerar isso uma "licença artística".

Assim funciona (espero que seja o que precisa):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void shuffle(int *array, int size) {
    for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int j = rand() % (i + 1);
        int tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0; 
    int c1[4][4], c2[4][4];
    int numbers[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) numbers[i] = i + 1;
    shuffle(numbers, 50);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
             c1[i][j] = numbers[i * 4 + j];
             printf("%i\t", c1[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    shuffle(numbers, 50);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
             c2[i][j] = numbers[i * 4 + j];
             printf("%i\t", c2[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    shuffle(numbers, 50);
    for (int k = 0; k < 50 && (p1 <= 16 || p2 <= 16); k++) {
        int sorteio = numbers[k];
        printf ("%i ", sorteio);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (c1[i][j] == sorteio) p1++;
                if (c2[i][j] == sorteio) p2++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (p1 == 16) printf("\nBingo! Jogador 1 ganhou\n");
    else if (p2 == 16) printf("\nBingo! Jogador 2 ganhou\n");
    else printf("\nempate");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/eUJiwC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/BingoGame). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/BingoGame.c).

Comment: Note que quando um dos dois jogadores chegar a 16 não deve mais entrar no loop.

Answer (score -1):

Existem erros de indentação e fechamento de chaves em local errado.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int sorteio = 0;
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0; 
    int c1[4][4], c2[4][4],i, j;
    for(i = 0;i < 4; i++ ){
         for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
             c1[i][j] = rand()%50;
             c2[i][j] = rand()%50;
         }
    }
    for(i = 0;i < 4; i++ ){
         for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
             printf("%i ",c1[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0;i < 4; i++ ){
         for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
             printf("%i ",c2[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
    }
    sorteio = rand() %50;
    printf ("%i ", sorteio);    
    while (p1 < 16 || p2 < 16){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
            for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (c1[i][j] == sorteio){
                p1++;
            }  
            if (c2[i][j] == sorteio){
                p2++;
            }
            }
        }
        sorteio = rand() %50;
        printf ("%i ", sorteio);
    }
    if (p1 == 16){
         printf("\nBingo! Jogador 1 ganhou\n");
         return 0;
    }
    else{   
          if (p2 == 16){
             printf("\nBingo! Jogador 2 ganhou\n");
             return 0;
            }
          else{
              printf("empate");
              return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```